# Google Apps Script Triggers not working (List Files and Folders within Gdrive Folder)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I created my first script by copying and pasting stuff from others. Somewhere down the line it look like I removed something that allows for triggers (both time & onchange) to work.

I tried applying some suggestions from other questions like these but without result..

```
function DolistFilesInFolder() {
  listFilesInFolder("specified folder"); //Enter folder name in between " "
}

function listFilesInFolder(folderName) {
  Logger.log(folderName);
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contentfolders = folder.getFolders();   //fetches the folders inside the folder
  var contentfiles = folder.getFiles();       //fetches the files inside the folder

  // Find or add sheet with folder name
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(folderName);
  if (sheet) {
    Logger.log("found");
  }
  else {
    sheet = ss.insertSheet(folderName);
  }
  sheet.clear();

  sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date", "URL"]);

  // Loop over folders in folder, using file iterator
  while (contentfolders.hasNext()) {
    var file = contentfolders.next();
    var data = [ 
      file.getName(),
      file.getDateCreated(),
      file.getUrl()
    ];

    sheet.appendRow(data);

    // Loop over files in folder, using file iterator
    while (contentfiles.hasNext()) {
    var file = contentfiles.next();
    var data = [ 
      file.getName(),
      file.getDateCreated(),
      file.getUrl()
    ];

    sheet.appendRow(data)


    }}
}
```

*For anyone interested this script lists both the Files and Folders in a Google Sheet based on the "specified folder"

Comment: Read about setting up triggers in the documentation.

Comment: Allright, so i should use onOpen(), I figured I want run the listFilesInFolder function on open so i tried renaming the DoListFilesInFolder function to onOpen(), but that didn't work.. 

function onOpen(){
  listFilesInFolder("DevcodeFile"); //Enter folder name in between " "
}

So what other content should I give to onOpen()

Comment: It looks good the way you did it. onOpen() is it called a simple trigger and may not be able to access Drive. You may have to set up the trigger manually.  Check out simple triggers in the docs. If you got a response from the logger for foldername then none of this applies.

Comment: I could not let it go. I took a look and simple trigger is the problem.  I would rename the file back to its original name and then set up the On Open Trigger manually.   -- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: adding this helped `function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onOpen()
      .create();
}`

Comment: You learn fast. Congratulations. I did not want to confuse the issue with an extra function but you have taken it to its logical conclusion.